# query 3 tables form db and get all columns of all tables

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, left-join

I have 3 tables products , category and product_category here are strutures of tables

1. products = id(pk), name , sku, ...
2. category = id(pk),name,parent_id(self relation)
3. product_category = category_id(fk), product_id(fk)

here is my query so for running

```
SELECT `products`.*,`product_category`.`category_id` as catid FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `product_category` ON products.id = product_category.item_id GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

it brings all products and category_id from product_category table i want data from category table as well like category.name . how i can do this?

Comment: Just do one more join with `category` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this not as simple as..?

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
     JOIN product_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_ID
     JOIN category c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id;
```

Comment: Looks correct, but note that `SELECT *` in general is usually not a good thing.

Comment: Considering the OP did not supply DDL, I have no way of knowing their column names. I'm pretty sure they don't have a column called `...`. :)

Comment: You certainly do have a way of knowing--comment on the question & answer when it is clear.